# Awk: merge orphaned text to specific field in line above

Tags: sed, awk

Given a tab-delimited text file containing item information:

```
41850   0.4     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Billy Makes a  Fridgewell, Norm 
Friend       
9338    0.4     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Shine, The Musical!     Mustard, Colonel   
7255    0.5     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Can You Play the   Truman, Harriet
Jew's Harp 
9314    0.5     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Hi, Skippy      Plum, Prof
```

Note the "orphaned" titles on two of the lines. Using Awk, how can I merge this orphan back into the title field above?

Pseudo-awk:

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]/{getline; ??? 
    if next line ~ /^[[:alpha:]]/ title=$7 + previous
    END{print $0}' <FILE
```

Anyway the steps seem to be:

Either

- Find "normal" lines,
- Test if following line is "orphan"
- if so, append "orphan" to field 7 [ title field ],
- Print line

or

- Find "orphans"
- Somehow append to field 7 of previous line [ there will never be two consecutive orphans ]

The first way seems easiest to me --- but then, I'm the one in ignorance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize the question is tagged `awk`, but this might be one of those times when it's easier with Perl:

```
perl -F"\t"  -lane 'BEGIN { $, = "\t" } 
            if (/^\d{2}/) { print @saved if @saved; @saved = @F } 
                     else { $saved[6].=" $_" }; 
                      END { print @saved }' foo.txt
```

Though here's an awk version of the same idea (with some improvements via Ed Morton):

```
awk -F"\t" '/^[0-9][0-9]/  { if (prefix) { print prefix"\t"title"\t"suffix }
                             prefix=$1
                             for ( i=2; i<=6; ++i ) prefix=prefix"\t"$i
                             title=$7; suffix=$8
                             next } 
                           { title = title" "$0 } 
                       END { print prefix"\t"title"\t"suffix }' foo.txt
```

Both scripts give me this output, which looks like what you want:

```
41850   0.4     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Billy Makes a Friend    Fridgewell, Norm 
9338    0.4     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Shine, The Musical!     Mustard, Colonel
7255    0.5     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Can You Play the Jew's Harp     Truman, Harriet
9314    0.5     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Hi, Skippy      Plum, Prof
```

Comment: That's a beaut!! I'll do some testing ...looks like this wins the goose!

Comment: For once, the perl is easier on the eyes. Using it! Thanks!

Comment: That's not any of the ways you'd really want to solve the problem with awk, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ tac file | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NF==1{s=" "$0;next} {$7=$7 s; s=""}1' | tac
41850   0.4     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Billy Makes a Friend    Fridgewell, Norm
9338    0.4     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Shine, The Musical!     Mustard, Colonel
7255    0.5     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Can You Play the Jew's Harp     Truman, Harriet
9314    0.5     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Hi, Skippy      Plum, Prof
```

Here's an alternative approach without tac and using GNU awk (just replace gensub() with 2 sub() calls or match() or whatever if you don't want to use gawk):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
NF==1 { s = gensub(/([^\t]+[\t]){6}[^\t]+/, "\\0 "$1, "", s); next }
      { printf "%s",s; s=$0 ORS }
END   { printf "%s",s }

$ gawk -f tst.awk file
41850   0.4     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Billy Makes a Friend    Fridgewell, Norm
9338    0.4     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Shine, The Musical!     Mustard, Colonel
7255    0.5     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Can You Play the Jew's Harp     Truman, Harriet
9314    0.5     0.5     LG      EN      RP      Hi, Skippy      Plum, Prof
```

Comment: +1 - using tac is a cute trick which definitely simplifies the awk code.   In your comment on my answer you said "any of the ways" - so what are some others?

Comment: The 2 other obvious ones are to save the records in an array and process them in the END section, or save the current line until the next line is read and then print it after changing $7 if appropriate, which is what you're doing, it's just using all those separate variables and negating the condition for the second part instead of using next and all those null-statements (trailing semi-colons) isn't the way to write it.

Comment: @Markreed: I posted an alternative that doesn't use tac so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements, @EdMorton.  I never got very far into awk - I went from doing everything I could possibly do with ksh builtins to using Perl, without much time in between. :)  I got rid of the extra semis and switched to `next`.  I thought about using an array instead of the separate vars; if awk had a way to get all of the fields in a single array, and copy them to another array in one go, I would have done that...

Comment: awk is about keeping the language small and simple so there's no language constructs to do things that are trivial with other language constructs. To copy array a to array b you just do "for(i in a)b[i]=a[i]" so literal assignment's still simply for numbers and strings but it's trivial do do "assignment for an array.

Comment: How does that gensub statement work Ed? I read that as: Group/capture 6 non-tabs, one or more, followed by 1 or more tabs, followed by 1 or more non-tabs --- then replace with [ is that a NULL char ] followed by the first field ...I don't know, not following along here.

Comment: @Bubnoff - it's grabbing 6 <non-tabs-followed-by-tab> strings, so that would match the first 6 fields plus the field separators between and after them, then grabbing the next string of non-tabs which would be the 7th field, then sticking a space followed by the contents of $1 after all of that.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;/\n\([^\t]*\t\)\{7\}/!s/\(\t[^\t]*\)\n\(.*\)/ \2\1/;P;D' file
```

Comment: orphaned fields need to be inserted into the right place in the preceding line, not just appended to the end.