# Faulty awk: translate spaces to tabs for one field only

Tags: awk

I received a PDF file of tabular data that I've converted to plaintext for processing.

```
pdftotext -nopgbrk -layout file.pdf
```

This does a pretty decent job but uses spaces to separate/delimit the fields in the columns and seems primarily interested in preserving the visual layout rather than 'structural' layout Ie., there is no consistent or reliable delimiter. So now I convert 2 or more spaces to tabs:

```
sed -i 's/[[:space:]]\{2,\}/\t/g' file.txt
```

Using `cat -vte` I see that this does a pretty nice job placing tabs in the file ....however, there are a few inconsistencies with the second field that I'd like to ask your help with.

Please see the following comparison for clarification:

Normal/Expected results:

```
79879   5.6     0.5     MG      EN      SQ      TFK World Report 09-24-2004     Time for Kids Editors,  ORD1915643
79880   5.5     0.5     MG      EN      SQ      TFK World Report 10-01-2004     Time for Kids Editors,  ORD1915643
79881   6.0     0.5     MG      EN      SQ      TFK World Report 10-08-2004     Time for Kids Editors,  ORD1915643
79882   5.5     0.5     MG      EN      SQ      TFK World Report 10-22-2004     Time for Kids Editors,  ORD1915643
79883   5.9     0.5     MG      EN      SQ      TFK World Report 10-29-2004     Time for Kids Editors,  ORD1915643
```

Some oddities and inconsistencies:

```
72      5.2 3.0 MG      EN      LS      Ramona and Her Father   Cleary, Beverly ORD2111460
491     4.8 4.0 MG      EN      LS      Ramona and Her Mother   Cleary, Beverly ORD1748201
134     5.6 3.0 MG      EN      LS      Ramona Quimby, Age 8    Cleary, Beverly ORD1748201
29      4.7     5.0 MG  EN      LS      From the Mixed-Up Files of Mrs. Basil E.        Konigsburg, E.L.        ORD1525579
```

Note that the 'smushing' effect may occur in either field 2 or field 3 ...AND, that the number of fields differs with the 'normal' results by either 1 or 2.

...So, to solve this I've tried stuff like the following:

```
awk -F'\t' 'OFS="\t";$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]/{print $1,gensub(/[[:space:]]/,"\t","g",$2),$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' file.txt
```

This seems to double each, or at least most, line(s) and cuts off fields.

**EDIT**
This seems to be working ...so far, still testing.

```
awk -F'\t' '{$2 = gensub( /[[:space:]]/, "\t", "g", $2 );
             $3 = gensub( /[[:space:]]/, "\t", "g", $3 )}
             {OFS="\t";print}' file.txt
```

Is there a simple way to solve this issue using awk?

**UPDATE**

Some have requested a sample representing the state just prior to my space tab conversion. The following represents a sample near where the previous sample is in the document. Looks about the same ...except one [below] is spaced, the other [above] tabbed. Note the way pdftotext deals with column 2 in the different samples below ...sometimes splitting, sometimes making a single column.

Sample 1:

```
    72   5.2 3.0 MG       EN   RP     Ramona and Her Father                     Cleary, Beverly              ORD0630871
are orphans
   491   4.8 4.0 MG       EN   RP     Ramona and Her Mother                     Cleary, Beverly              ORD0785414
are also orphans
   186   4.8 4.0 MG       EN   RP     Ramona Forever                            Cleary, Beverly              ORD0630871
forever the orphan
```

Sample 2:

```
  79871    5.7   0.5   MG   EN    SQ        TFK World Report 03-18-2005         Time for Kids Editors,       ORD1915643
  79872    5.8   0.5   MG   EN    SQ        TFK World Report 04-01-2005         Time for Kids Editors,       ORD1915643
  79873    6.0   0.5   MG   EN    SQ        TFK World Report 04-08-2005         Time for Kids Editors,       ORD1915643
```

**UPDATE 2**

Made the following changes to Ed's submission. Thinking it could be simplified, but it works. It has to allow for the orphaned lines.

```
$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+/{
   for (i=1;i<=6;i++)
      printf "%s\t", $i

   n = split($0,tmp,/  +/)

   for (i=2;i>=0;i--)
      printf "%s\t", tmp[n-i]

   print ""
}
$1 ~ /^[^[:digit:]]+/ {print $0}
```

Maybe this is prettier:

```
{
        if ($1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+/) {
                for (i=1;i<=6;i++)
                printf "%s\t", $i

                n = split($0,tmp,/  +/)

                for (i=2;i>=0;i--)
                printf "%s\t", tmp[n-i]

                print ""
        }
        else print $0;
}
```

Comment: If no fields are empty, you could compress tabs the same way you did with spaces.

Comment: If you can post some raw data, we can test our answers.  Much better than wasting time on guesses.  Also check out [`unexpand(1)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unexpand) to convert spaces to tabs. It may not be applicable for your use, but it's a handy tool to know about.

Comment: @ghoti ~ first, the second table above is raw data. Large spaces are tabs. Second,  knew about unexpand, but as you mention, not applicable here. Thanks

Comment: I don't see how your second table can be translated to the first table using this script.  If you can show *data-before*, *your-result* and *intended result*, it will help us adjust your code to meet your requirements.

Comment: @ghoti ~ I apologize, it honestly didn't occur to me that you were talking about the pre-tab/space conversion. To clarify, both tables are results of the sed statement, but because the columns are not spaced in a consistent way after the pdftotext conversion, I didn't think there was a way to get perfect tabs in one go. Some columns have one space, some have untold numbers ...for the same field!

Comment: The updated post contains 'untainted' samples of the document just after the pdftotext conversion. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Are those 2 different sections of the same file or sections from 2 different files?

Comment: The last 2 samples are from different points in the same file

Comment: How do YOU know that "5.7   0.5   MG" should just be one field or that "5.2 3.0 MG" should be 3 fields? Which is correct?

Comment: It should be 3 fields. The headers on the table were stripped out ...my bad.

Comment: In your modified scripts, "if (x) {doY} else {doZ}" is better than "x{doY} !x(doZ)" but the idiomatic awkish way to do it is "x{doY;next}{doZ}". if..else is fine too for your example. Also the negation of $1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+/ is $1 !~ /^[[:digit:]]+/, not $1 ~ /^[^[:digit:]]+/.

Comment: @EdMorton, you can make code in comments much more readable by using `backticks`.

Comment: @Graham: Aha! thanks I thought there had to be a way. I'll try it in this comment. the negation of `$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+/` is `$1 !~ /^[[:digit:]]+/`. And now to try escaping them: x=\`foo\`. OK, good. Don't suppose there's a way to get newlines into comments is there?

Comment: @EdMorton, Nope, no newlines in comments.
That is, you can put them in, but the site removes them.  I guess it's a strategy for keeping answers in answers. You can also double your "outside" backticks to put backticks inside backticks: ``pi=`dc -e '2k22 7/p'` ``

Comment: @Graham great, thanks. Been using the site about a week now, obviously I'm still learning. I've been using usenet for years and it's nice to be able to edit your posts here but _darn_ it's hard to find the threads you're interested/involved in!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than us starting with the output of a sed command that may be what is corrupting your data, post your data BEFORE you run that sed command on it and let us go from there. I suspect that since you say the PDF conversion tool preserves the "visual layout" that the right solution is probably to simply use gawk's FIELDWIDTHS capability on that so you parse the PDF converters output based on the width of the fields rather than trying to figure out how many spaces it takes to represent a field separator.

EDIT: here's a match()-based solution for comparison, but I actually now think @ghoti is right and the solutions is simpler than this:

```
$ cat file
    72   5.2 3.0 MG       EN   RP     Ramona and Her Father     Cleary, Beverly    ORD0630871
   491   4.8 4.0 MG       EN   RP     Ramona and Her Mother     Cleary, Beverly    ORD0785414
  79872  5.8  0.5  MG  EN   SQ    TFK World Report 04-01-2005  Time for Kids Editors,  ORD1915643
  79873  6.0  0.5  MG  EN   SQ    TFK World Report 04-08-2005  Time for Kids Editors,  ORD1915643
$
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
   whl = "([[:digit:]]+)"
   dec = "([[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+)"
   wrd = "([^ ]+)"
   rst = "(.*)"
   s   = "[ ]+"
   fmt = whl s dec s dec s wrd s wrd s wrd s rst
}
{
   match($0,fmt,arr)
   split(arr[7],tmp,/  +/)
   arr[7] = tmp[1]
   arr[8] = tmp[2]
   arr[9] = tmp[3]

   for (i=1;i<=9;i++)
      printf "<%s>", arr[i]
   print ""
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
<72><5.2><3.0><MG><EN><RP><Ramona and Her Father><Cleary, Beverly><ORD0630871>
<491><4.8><4.0><MG><EN><RP><Ramona and Her Mother><Cleary, Beverly><ORD0785414>
<79872><5.8><0.5><MG><EN><SQ><TFK World Report 04-01-2005><Time for Kids Editors,><ORD1915643>
<79873><6.0><0.5><MG><EN><SQ><TFK World Report 04-08-2005><Time for Kids Editors,><ORD1915643>
```

EDIT: yeah, here's a simpler solution, just print the first 6 fields and then split the rest on a multi-space separator:

```
$ cat tst2.awk
{
   for (i=1;i<=6;i++)
      printf "<%s>", $i

   n = split($0,tmp,/  +/)

   for (i=2;i>=0;i--)
      printf "<%s>", tmp[n-i]

   print ""
}
$
$ awk -f tst2.awk file
<72><5.2><3.0><MG><EN><RP><Ramona and Her Father><Cleary, Beverly><ORD0630871>
<491><4.8><4.0><MG><EN><RP><Ramona and Her Mother><Cleary, Beverly><ORD0785414>
<79872><5.8><0.5><MG><EN><SQ><TFK World Report 04-01-2005><Time for Kids Editors,><ORD1915643>
<79873><6.0><0.5><MG><EN><SQ><TFK World Report 04-08-2005><Time for Kids Editors,><ORD1915643>
```

Comment: The widths are not consistent in any way after the pdftotext step. The sed statement just looks for splits of 2 spaces or more. I will post an original snippet so you can see. It wouldn't be the first time I've missed something embarrassingly obvious ...won't be the last, unfortunately.

Comment: I have added samples from the original ...just after the pdf to text conversion.

Comment: I'm experimenting with your FIELDWIDTH idea. Problem is that it's difficult to assign widths to the first few columns that allow for higher numbers while still separating the fields correctly. If you're interested I'll post my trials above.

Comment: I'm now thinking that a GNU awk match() solution populating the optional 3rd arg array might be what you really need. I'm going to poke at that a bit and get back to you.

Comment: I think this is it! Am testing ...to be continued.

Comment: When I test this it prints the first 6 fields twice. OOps, nevermind ..saw your edits

Comment: This works. I made some changes to allow for orphaned lines ...please see my update in the original post.

Comment: I still don't see any "orphaned lines" in your posted sample input.

Comment: Added what they look like. You tackled this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096545/awk-merge-orphaned-text-to-specific-field-in-line-above. I like to tackle these types of issues in separate steps, but maybe I shouldn't in this case. I've made alot of assumptions. Basically I was hoping this would be simple enough for a few one-liners and I wouldn't have to try and remember perl.

Comment: It would certainly make it less frustrating for us trying to help you if you just posted the whole thing up front so we don't have to keep changing our scripts. You do not need perl for parsing text files. So you just want the "orphaned" lines ignored since the text from them doesn't appear in your sample output, right?

Comment: Understood -- my apologies. My basic idea was to turn the document into a tab-delimited file for input to a different script. As to the orphans --- I'd like them printed exactly, as is ...completely ignored. The unforeseen issue in my "orphans" question, is that the number of fields fluctuates wildly. So to get a consistent "orphans" solution, I need to get reliable fields, Ie., will the title field be 7 or 8 or 9.

Comment: After playing with the regex for the leading characters a bit, I've got my tab-delimited file. CAse closed! thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your original awk script seems to double each line because `OFS="\t"` evaluates to `true`, therefore prints the current line.  Put this in a `BEGIN{}` block to avoid the repeats:

```
gawk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]/ {print $1,gensub(/[[:space:]]/,"\t","g",$2),$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' file.txt
```

Note that `gensub()` is part of `gawk`, so is not portable.  You can achieve the same thing portably with this:

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]/ {gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"\t",$2); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' file.txt
```

That said ... with your update, I can see that the original data is well-enough formatted that we can probably just process it as-is.  Annoying that you have only a single space between columns 2 and 4, or we could simply use multiple-spaces as a field separator.  But it's an predictable input format nevertheless.

It seems that for your first 6 fields, input is separated by "any whitespace", and for the last 3 fields, it is separated by "two or more spaces".  With that in mind, we could use the following awk to parse your input data:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS="  +";
  fmt="----\n1=%s\n2=%s\n3=%s\n4=%s\n5=%s\n6=%s\n7=%s\n8=%s\n9=%s\n";
}

{
  # Grab the right-hand fields, separated by FS
  a[7]=$(NF-2); a[8]=$(NF-1); a[9]=$NF;

  # Then trim the line and grab initial fields, separated by whitespace
  sub(/^ +/, "");
  split($0, easy, /[[:space:]]+/);
  for(i=1;i<=6;i++) {
    a[i]=easy[i+1];
  }

  printf(fmt, a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9]);
}
```

This assumes that the break between your second last field and last field will ALWAYS have more than 1 space (as is shown in the input data you've supplied in your question).  You/we can code around this if this isn't a safe assumption.

Adjust the output as you see fit.

Comment: +1 for spotting the easy way to do it, it inspired me to re-think the match() approach I was working on!

Comment: Toss up between yours and Ed's. Yours works as well. Upvoted!

Comment: FYI the functional difference is that mine would work with or without white space at the start of the line. That's because I changed the FS for the end of the line rather than the start.

Comment: Alrighty, I've kept FS the same, but removed the sensitivity to leading whitespace with a `sub()`.

Comment: sigh.  tnx.  silly shift key.  Fixed.  It was supposed to be `/^ +/`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `{print $1,gensub(/[[:space:]]/,"\t","g",$2),$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}`, try:

```
{ $2 = gensub( /[[:space:]]/, "\t", "g", $2 ); print }
```

Comment: This looks like what I was shooting for but couldn't get the syntax right. Thanks. Will test later this morning.

Comment: This isn't going to work. There seems to be a conflict between my replacement, which is a tab, and the fact that both the FS and OFS are tabs. It is still duplicating lines ...not only that, but doesn't have any effect on the column in question. Using: `awk -F'\t' 'OFS="\t";{$2 = gensub( /[[:space:]]/, "\t", "g", $2 );print}'`

Comment: This seems to be working: `awk -F'\t' '{$2 = gensub( /[[:space:]]/, "\t", "g", $2 )}{OFS="\t";print}'`. Still testing.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
column -t file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: This splits fields like titles and authors. Too aggressive -- also, inconsistent. Thanks though.

Comment: When I specify a delimiter it does about the same job as pdftotext but with other 'oddities' added. `column -t -s'\t'`

Answer (score 1):

I gather that only the 2nd and 3rd columns from the end can actually have spaces in them?

I'd try something like this bit of Python:

```
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    start = line.rstrip().split(None, 6)
    end = start.pop().rsplit(None, 1)
    mid = re.split('\s\s+', end.pop(0), maxsplit=1)
    print '\t'.join(start + mid + end)
```

---

edit: OK, if you want to stick with coreutils/textutils tools, here's a sed script that does roughly the same thing as the above Python:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
s/^ *//
s/ \+/\t/
s/ \+/\t/
s/ \+/\t/
s/ \+/\t/
s/ \+/\t/
s/ \+/\t/
s/ \+\([^ ]\+\) *$/\t\1/
s/  \+/\t/
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
sed -e 's/^ *//; s/ \+/\t/; s/ \+/\t/; s/ \+/\t/; s/ \+/\t/; s/ \+/\t/; s/ \+/\t/; s/ \+\([^ ]\+\) *$/\t\1/; s/  \+/\t/'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm hoping to stick to standard utilities for eventual inclusion in a make file or bash script, however.